# Pandas merge sequential matching pairs only

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Table1

```
Oid, T1
10, 1493955900309445045
10, 1493955900321006000
10, 1493955900322255462
11, 14910000
```

table 2:

```
Oid,T2
10, 1493955900309206537
10, 1493955900320695981
11, 1490000


Expected merge output
Oid,T1,T2
10, 1493955900309445045,1493955900309206537
10, 1493955900321006000,1493955900320695981
#ignored 10, 1493955900322255462 #mapped nowhere
11, 14910000,1490000
```

Basically merge first instances of matching and ignore remaining.
I know data is sequentially arranged (with some values missing table 2), so I need to ignore those cases. For simplicity we can assume Table 1 as start of some task and table 2 contains end of some task. Someday task may end but not end !. I think this could be done by indexing

Additional :

Suppose we want to merge only when number of entries in both Oid are same. 
Expected merge output becomes

```
Oid,T1,T2
#ignored all Oid = 10,because there count in table 1=3,table2=3
11, 14910000,1490000
```

Another example

```
>>> df1
   Oid    ts
0   10  1000
1   10  1001
2   20  2000
3   20  2001
4   30  3000
5   40  4000
>>> df2
   Oid   ts2
0   10  1006
1   10  1007
2   10  1008
3   20  2005
4   20  2004
5   30  3003
6   40  4004
7   40  4008

Expected Output
Oid    ts    ts2
20    2000    2005
20    2001    2004
30    3000    3003
```

I think using value_counts should help, I did

```
>>> df1.Oid.value_counts()
20    2
10    2
30    1
40    1
Name: Oid, dtype: int64
>>> df2.Oid.value_counts()
10    3
20    2
40    2
30    1
```

Now take only, 20 and 30 because only there count match. I think I need to create list of good orders that will be filtered from df1 and df2 and then merged.

@jezrael your answer seems to work on whole column and NOT each unique entry in Oid column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for count duplicates by column `Oid` and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html). Last remove helper column `new` by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df1['new'] = df1.groupby('Oid').cumcount()
df2['new'] = df2.groupby('Oid').cumcount()

print (df1)
   Oid                   T1  new
0   10  1493955900309445045    0
1   10  1493955900321006000    1
2   10  1493955900322255462    2
3   11             14910000    0

print (df2)
   Oid                   T2  new
0   10  1493955900309206537    0
1   10  1493955900320695981    1
2   11              1490000    0    

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Oid','new']).drop('new', axis=1)
print (df)
   Oid                   T1                   T2
0   10  1493955900309445045  1493955900309206537
1   10  1493955900321006000  1493955900320695981
2   11             14910000              1490000
```

EDIT For check if columns are same use [`equals`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.equals.html):

```
if df1['Oid'].equals(df2['Oid']):
    print ('eq')
    #another code
else:
    print ('no')
    #another code
```

Another possible solution is only test values in columns are same with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) (same as `==`) and [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html):

```
if (df1['Oid'].eq(df2['Oid'])).all():
    print ('eq')
    #another code
else:
    print ('no')
    #another code
```

EDIT1:

First get `oids` which have same length:

```
a = df1.Oid.value_counts()
b = df2.Oid.value_counts()

df1 = df1.set_index('Oid')
df2 = df2.set_index('Oid')

c = pd.concat([a,b], axis=1, keys=('a','b'))
oids = c.index[c['a'] == c['b']]
print (oids)
Int64Index([20, 30], dtype='int64')
```

Then select by `oids` and `concat`:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1.loc[oids],df2.loc[oids]], axis=1).reset_index()
print (df3)
   Oid    ts   ts2
0   20  2000  2005
1   20  2001  2004
2   30  3000  3003
```

Comment: does drop automatically know that it has to (not match) unmatched new columns ! is drop specifically for a purpose like this?

Comment: Is there a way to ignore the merge if number of entries for each Oid in df1 and df2 are not same? I mean I need to put a check thatif number of entries are not same in df1 and df2 then just ignore that Oid. Else do what we are doing now (cumcount and then merge)

Comment: Hmmm, I think [`equals`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.equals.html) should works -  `if df1['Oid'].equals(df2['Oid']) #not merge else #do merge`

Comment: I updated my question with additional info to make it clear.` if df1['Oid'].equals(df2['Oid'])` does it understand that it has to check counts for each Oid ?

Comment: Yes, it compare column `Oid` in both datafrems if equals.

Comment: Added 1 more example, I think you did not understand my question correctly. I am not comparing lengths of Oid columns but lengths of each unique Id in Oid columns

Comment: Hmmm, it is more complicated.

Comment: Not easy, but I try add solution. please check it.